# Non-contractible space with trivial homotopy groups

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

What is an example of a non-contractible space $X$ with $\pi_n(X) = 0$ for all $n\geq 0$ (note in particular $X$ is path connected)?

Motivation: Whitehead's theorem implies that no such CW complex $X$ exists. I'd like to know a counterexample to the "general Whitehead theorem".

Comment: [The closed topologists's sine curve, also known as the Warsaw circle](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a2/Warsaw_Circle.png/220px-Warsaw_Circle.png)

Comment: @BalarkaSen ah, of course. I was hoping for something more exotic. I guess the next question is to ask for locally path connected.

Comment: @Timkinsella: You should then modify your question so it asks what you actually want to ask. (An even more challenging question would be a space which is locally contractible, weakly contractible but not contractible.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A nice example is the (open) [long line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_line_(topology)).  Every compact subset of it is contained in a bounded interval which is homeomorphic to $[0,1]$, and thus the homotopy groups are trivial (and the space is additionally locally contractible, even locally Euclidean!).  However, it is not contractible, essentially because it's "too long" to contract the whole thing with a single interval.

Comment: that is the level of exoticism I was looking for. And I think it answers the question @MoisheCohen poses in his comment.

Comment: @Timkinsella: Except I had in mind metrizable spaces...

Answer (score 3):

You can find many examples among finite topological spaces. For information on these, you can browse Jonathan Barmak's LNM book in the subject.

Comment: I would add for those unfamiliar with finite topological spaces that every finite space is locally contractible.

Answer (score 2):

Quasi-circle, which is defined in exercise 7 of page 79 in Hatcher’s book Algebraic topology